# Is there any way to install RMongo package as its officially removed from CRAN?

Tags: r, installation, package, rmongo

I need to install RMongo to connect to my local MongoDB database. On installing RMongo I am getting this error:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘RMongo’ is not available (for R version 3.5.3)
```

I also downloaded RMongo tar file and stored in R directory where all packages get installed and tried to install the package by writing this command in R environment

```
install.packages("C:/Users/Akash/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/RMongo_0.0.25.tar", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

On trying to download the package through tar file I am getting this error,

**Warning: invalid package 'C:/Users/Akash/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/RMongo_0.0.25.tar'
Error: ERROR: no packages specified
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/Akash/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/RMongo_0.0.25.tar’ had non-zero exit status**

Any help is appreciated
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you get any error message when installing from the tar? If so, please list them. Otherwise it's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: While I don't use Mongo, might I offer an alternative? Since `RMongo`'s last release was allegedly [in 2013](https://github.com/cran/RMongo), perhaps [`mongolite`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mongolite/index.html) will work for you? It is much more current and alleges to be a *"High-performance MongoDB client"*.

Comment: bit_zoom, I suggest you briefly read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting for formatting questions. It can make a significant difference in quick interpretation (said differently, unformatted or incorrectly/poorly formatted questions look more difficult, so I often just skip them without reading).